# Are there any Android device dumps available to be used as datasets?

Tags: mobile, android, forensics

I'm interested in finding Android device data dumps so as to use in my PhD research, concerning data analysis. I have only been able to encounter two sources online; one of them unavailable at the given time. I will share the resources with you, in case someone also needs, but I would also like to ask if there are other sources available, because the ones I have encountered do not have a satisfactory amount of data to be used in analysis by Machine Learning or Computational Intelligence techniques.

1. [DigitalCorpora](http://digitalcorpora.org) (currently offline - I will edit if something changes)

   Contains (among others) multiple android data dumps from a Nexus S1 and a Nexus One device. However, the data are few and repeated.(No calls, no sent sms, one contact in the contacts.db)
2. [CFReDs](http://www.cfreds.nist.gov/)

   Contains, among multiple old phone versions, two data dumps concerning Android devices and I also noticed a dump from an iPhone 3GS. The dumps are in .pdf, .html, .ufdr (Cellebrite's UFED file format - commercial licence needed) and xml. Unfortunately, the data are not enough in this case as well.

Finally, would you recommend that I created my own dataset?

Comment: Disclaimer: When referring to "usage for data analysis", I certainly mean separate usage of different databases within the dumps.

Comment: The digitalcorpora.org ([link](http://digitalcorpora.org)) website came back online.